# How to interpret the negative volatility of the single stock, after neutralizing against the index?

Tags: volatility, capm

I am trying to find the statistical significance of the certain events on volatility, such as divided/earningsdate/M&A, etc on single stock wise compared to no events. Commonsensewise, these events would bump the volatiliy of the stocks. So actually the volatiliy of these stocks in those particular dates actually has the statistically significant difference from normal trading days.

However, when I try to neutralize those volatility against the index volatility, so that I can rule out some noises that are not related to single stock wise, I am getting the negative volatility results as the residuals.
I am using Python for neutralization, and the code is similar to this:

```
Y = df['singlestockvol'].values 
X  = df['indexvol'].values
model = sm.OLS(Y,X)
results = model.fit()
print(results.summary())
df['predictedvol'] = results.fittedvalues
df['adjvol'] = df['singlestockvol'] - df['predictedvol']
```

Here are some samples that I have got:

[image: Sampples]

So according to CAPM model, the adjvol would be the excess volatility that I want to extract. However, considering there are many data that has negative volatility, is there something wrong from this approach?

Edit: adding the OLS results for better reference.

[image]

Comment: This is hard to reproduce without the data. It would help if you share a sample. Can you at least show the reslt of `results.summary()`. What is `intravol`?

Comment: SOrry for the vague information. Hope this clarifies a bit.

Comment: Did you use variance in your OLS instead of vola? Perhaps you try $\sigma_i^2=\beta_{i,m}^2{\sigma_m^2}+\epsilon_i^2$ and solve for your adjvola?

Comment: For the volatility, I didn't use the variance. Just used the Garman Klass estimator for calculating single stock intraday volatility. Maybe subtract the sqrt(predicted volatility) for this case, and get the square root of the df['adjvol'] of the result you meaN?

Comment: @celi By using Garman-Kohlhagen vola (?) you are using implied vola instead of hist vola? Is this correct?

Comment: yes you are right. Am using the intraday vol estimator for the dataset. Maybe that's the reason?